# Are the weak* and the sequential weak* closures the same?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a question that might be easy for the experts.

Let $E$ be a Banach space (non-separable) and let $E'$ be its dual space. Suppose that $X\subset E'$ and assume that $X$ is separable with respect to the weak* topology.

My question is the following:

> Are the sequential weak* closure and the weak* closure of $X$ equal?

Google was not able to help me on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

For a specific, non-separable counter-example take $E=\ell_\infty$. Then the set $$X=\{e_n^*\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq \ell_\infty^*$$ consisting of evaluation functionals  is bounded but not weak* compact. (Here $\langle e_n^*, f\rangle = f(n)$ for $f\in \ell_\infty$.) However, by boundedness, the weak* closure of $X$ is compact in the weak* topology hence different from $X$. There are no non-eventually constant convergent sequences in $X$ so the cluster points of $X$ cannot be realised as limits of sequences.

To be more precise, the weak*-sequential closure of $X$ is $X$ itself but $X$ is not weak*-closed (because it is not weak*-compact) so the weak* closure of $X$ is strictly bigger than $X$.

Comment: can you explain with more details your last sentence ? I don't understand it right now

Comment: ok but what is then the weak-* closure of $X$ ?

Comment: @user1952009, $\ell_\infty\cong C(\beta \mathbb{N})$. Then $X=\{\delta_n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The closure of $X$ is just $\{\delta_x\colon x\in \beta \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: .. I don't know what means $\beta \mathbb{N}$ and $C(\beta \mathbb{N})$

Comment: @user1952009 $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of the natural numbers; $C(\beta \mathbb{N})$ is the Banach space of continuous functions on $\beta \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: really, we need some complicated concepts like those to find an example of weak-* closure $\ne$ sequence weak-* closure, i.e. that nets are different of sequences in topology of  Banach spaces?

Comment: and is the fact that $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is non-separable important for the fact that weak^* sequential closure isn't weak closure ?

Comment: until now I cannot represent myself what really means geometrically the weak-* closure, I guess it is quite normal, since the OP had obviously the same problem

Comment: ok ! thank you !! I asked this 2 or 3 times, nobody answered me. I understand better now why it is quite a complicated concept : non-separable spaces are much more complicated in deep nature

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=E'=L_{2}(R)$ then $ X=l_{2}(N) \subset E'= E $, this is well-defined by considering a trivial extension from functions in $l_{2}$ to $L_{2}(R)$  (define $f=0$ for all $x \in R\setminus N$ ). Then $X$ is a separable Hilbert space and weak-star and weak topology on $X$ coincides!

Obviously sequentially weakly closed does not imply weakly closedness in $X$. one counter example is the set $\{ \sqrt n  e_n~ | \quad n \in N  \}.$